# Where to put chained actions in React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, flux

Fairly simple use case: I have actions/events that will cause an ajax request to be executed and then update a list.

The problem is I'm not sure how (specifically, *where* to kick off a request for a new list when the page is changed.

redux store

```
const defaultStore = {
  list: [],
  page: 1    
};
```

Wrapper Component

```
const wrapper = props => (
  <div>
    <List {...props}> {/* This list should have page controls */}
      <PageControls {...props} />
    </List>
    <List /> {/* This list should not have page controls */}
  </div>
);
```

List component

```
const List = props => (
  <div>
    {props.children} {/* render page controls if present */}
    {props.items.map((item, k) => <div key={k}>item</div>
  </div>
);
```

Pager Controls component

```
const PageControls = props => (
  <div>
    <span onClick={props.changePage(-1)}>Backward</span>
    <span onClick={props.changePage(1)}>Forward</span>
  </div>
);
```

actionCreator

```
function changePage(delta) {
  return {
    type: 'CHANGE_PAGE',
    delta
  };
}

// utilizes react-thunk middleware
function getList(page = 1) {
  return dispatch => 
    axios.get(`/path/to/api?page=${page}`)
      .then(res => dispatch(updateList(res.data));
}

function updateList(newList) {
  return { 
    type: 'UPDATE_LIST',
    newList
  };
}
```

reducer

```
function reducer(state = {}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'CHANGE_PAGE':
      return {...state, page: state.page + action.delta};
    case 'UPDATE_LIST':
      return {...state, list: action.newList};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

At this point I could do a couple of things -- I could make every actionCreator that should trigger a list update dispatch that action:

```
function changePage(delta) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'CHANGE_PAGE',
      delta
    });

    return dispatch(getList(store.getState() + delta));
  }
}
```

But this seems messy.  Now not only do I have to get my `store` but I also have to turn every actionCreator that affects the list into a thunk.

The only other thing I can think of is to have my `<List>` component use `store.subscribe` somewhere to watch for changes to page and then kick off another `getList` action, but this also seems like I'm moving the understanding of what does and does not trigger state changes out of Redux and into my React components.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, maybe you should change your approach. I don't see a reason to make two actions for changing page and retrieving the list. You can just dispatch `getPage()` action on button click, passing next page number. This should retrieve list of items and refresh your page.

In your store you should keep track on current page, so each time page refreshes the value of `getPage()` argument will also update.

For example (assuming that current page is not retrieved from API):

```
function getPage(page = 1) {
  return dispatch => 
    axios.get(`/path/to/api?page=${page}`)
      .then(res => dispatch(updatePage(res.data, page));
}

function updatePage(newList, currentPage) {
  return { 
    type: 'UPDATE_PAGE',
    newList,
    currentPage,
  };
}
```

and connect required components to the store, in your case it would be `List` and `PageControls` components.

```
const PageControls = props => (
  <div>
    <span onClick={props.getPage(props.currentPage - 1)}>Backward</span>
    <span onClick={props.getPage(props.currentPage + 1)}>Forward</span>
  </div>
);
```

This will allow you to maintain simple and clean code. Also you can trigger it from multiple, not related components.

Comment: This works, thank you.  My only question would be, is this how redux is meant to be used?  I'm essentially calling a function that performs async and then dispatches an action.  This doesn't seem that much different from performing the async call in a component.  I thought the idea in Redux is that the state responds to action submissions, rather than action submissions being dispatched after fetching state.

Comment: Yes. The idea of redux is to make global store available from every component in application. It also applies to redux actions. Of course there are multiple ways how to make fetching data and then dispatching redux actions however keeping it in one, single place not related to components is always the best idea. This way you make your application more scalable in the future. Components should be always as simple as it is possible and, well it should only present data or take input, no background logic. You can also read about redux-saga. More advanced usage of redux using generators.